# How to keep a line under the text when resizing a symbol

Tags: sketch-app

I'm trying to create a 'header/title' like text with a line underneath as a symbol. But I'm struggling with resizing the symbol.

This is what the symbol itself looks like:

[image: the symbol]

And here is a resized instance of the symbol:

[image: resized symbol]

As shown in the image above; the title gets cut off.
I've tried finicking with the resizing options, but alas to no avail (yet).

What I'd like is that the line stays underneath the title and the title should be center aligned. Here is a (custom made) example of a possible end result:

[image: possible end result]

I know that text elements have an underline option, but this is not always appropriate in my design. But I'll use it as a last resort if resizing is a no go.

---

Forgive me if this question is already asked somewhere, I've tried searching but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin like [Paddy](https://github.com/DWilliames/paddy-sketch-plugin) could help you. After setting the space between the line and the text it automatically resizes the box containing both text and line when you type more.

Comment: Great, this does _exactly_ what I want! Thanks for the heads up Helena!